# how to force stop any plugin if the app is killed from the recent menu

Tags: android, flutter, android-lifecycle

I want to force kill a plugin I am using in my app after the app is killed from the recent apps menu or any menu in fact.

the plugin is a notification layout of media controls. when the app is killed the controls in the notification area are still up and tapping it would cause errors and the system would loop with the "your app has stopped working" message

the plugin in question is: https://github.com/moda20/fading_edge_scrollview and it is maintained by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the app process when invoking ‘onDestroy()’, then anything started by the app will be terminated.

Take a look at this library:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix